# Filtering on multiple DataTables with First DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am trying to export to database tables details into Multiple Worksheets Inside a Single Excel File and I got export working correct, but the issue with multiple DataTable Filtering with First DataTable Email Id.

Below is my C# Code:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Registration Details");

    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Education Details");

    dt = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate1(bo);

    dt1 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate2(bo);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

    ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "Users.xls", Page.Response);   

}
```

I have two tables Registration_table and Education_table and also have two DataTable Registration details and Education details.

I need result base on email id's of first DataTable(dt) that first DataTable emails id's users only should come into second DataTable that means education details based on email ids.

Suppose below is first DataTable details.

```
sno    email            mobile        city

 1     raj@gmail.com     123456789    hyderabad
```

I need result of second DataTable details like below single users.

```
sno       email              education 

 1        raj@gmail.com       MBA
```

And I am using two stored procedures for first getting registration details and second Education Details.

Comment: You can simply modify your Stored Procedure to fetch data based on email present in `Registration_table`.

Comment: How to pass first DataTable Email Ids, Above I used first datatable method : Get_Registrationdetailsbydate1(bo);, Can you update answer. @Rahul Singh

Comment: What I mean is just pass the parameter to your Stored Procedure which is fetching educational details and in SP simply filter the data with _WHERE_ clause.

Comment: I think, its simple but getting confused, I used this method for getting registration details:
    dt = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate1(bo); and this method is use for getting education details.

    dt1 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate2(bo);. but after filling of first datatable, how to pass parameter to second procedure means how to get email ids from first datatable dt to second dt1. @Rahul Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the best approach would be to do this at the database end itself, i.e. when you fetch the registration details based on those details query the education details too, but if your logic is very complicated rather than simple tables then you will have to loop through your `Registration` DataTable and pass the email address as parameter to fetch Education details. Altough it will be compilcated approach since you will have to store all he emails in Registration table and then fetch Education details.

```
foreach(DataRow row in  dtRegistration.Rows)
{
    string Email = row.Field<string>("Email");
    //store it in a collection or comma separeted string and pass it to
    //bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate2(bo); table.
}
```

If you don't have huge data and you are fine with current code on how both datatable are populated then let the code be as it is and simply use *LINQ* to filter you Education datatable like this:-

```
DataTable filteredEducation = dtEducation.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(x => dtRegistration.AsEnumerable()
                           .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email") == x.Field<string>("Email")))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```

You will have to import `System.Linq` *namespace*.

**Update:**

Finally your button clcik handler should look like this:-

```
dt = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate1(bo);
dt1 = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate2(bo);
DataTable filteredEducation = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                 .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email") == x.Field<string>("Email")))
                           .CopyToDataTable();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Tables.Add(filteredEducation);
ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "DangoteUsers.xls", Page.Response);
```

Comment: Can you update loop code also, as you said, i have to loop through your Registration DataTable and pass the email address as parameter to fetch Education details. bo.para1 is passing parameters, I am not aware of linq or update answer as above code. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @zahed - Updated but as I said it will be compicated, try LINQ approach its very easy and straighforward.

Comment: Actual i have thousand of data, then how to pass parameter through linq, the above your linq answer getting confused to me, can you update clearly according to my code, please dont mind. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @zahed - No need to pass any parameter through LINQ that's what I said. You already have both datatables right? You want to filter second table based on first. Exactly that we are doing with LINQ, Where caluse will filter with those email which are present in _Registration_ DataTable.

Comment: Then please update all button_click code answer, according to my above C# question code, it will help more to me, already i have two datatable mention in above question code, waiting for your linq updated answer. @Rahul Singh

Comment: Thank you, I will check and update my answer, one more thing, if i need another third datatable and want to same check like above using email id to registration as education then i have to use same mothod for another datatable na. @Rahul Singh

Comment: Yes you will have to make one more datatable but logic will remain same.

Comment: Thank you very much, but some 5 to 6 records is missing according to searching date wise. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @zahed - You're Welcome, Maybe some records might be missing cz of whitespace issue. Use `Trim` while comparing the records.

Comment: where I have to use trim and how?. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @zahed - While comparing email address here: `z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim()` but please check for nulls first otherwise it may throw _Null Reference Exception_.

Comment: I did but some record is missing one more think in my education table multiple email id is there of same user, there no null values also because, every values are inserted using session so there is no chance of null. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @zahed - Okay but somehow its comparison issue only please check those records which are missing if they have are different or soemthing.

Comment: Ok, but when user register that email id only will inserted into education table using session, if email id is missing in registration table, its also should miss into education table. @Rahul Singh

Comment: @zahed - According to the query only those records will be fetched in `filteredEducation` table which are present in `Registration`  table that is the reason I am saying please check the condition and please debug and try a bit.

Comment: Ok thank you, let I will check inform you tomorow. @Rahul Singh